# Symbolize_keys showing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
hash = { 'name' => 'Rob', 'age' => '28' }
hash.symbolize_keys
```

but got error 
: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for {"name"=>"Rob", "age"=>"28"}:Hash in irb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`symbolize_keys` does not exist in vanilla ruby. Either run `rails console` instead of just `irb` or require active support beforehand.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

hash = { 'name' => 'Rob', 'age' => '28' }
hash.symbolize_keys # => {:name=>"Rob", :age=>"28"}
```

Comment: require 'active_support/core_ext' is wat i missed